# Which topics are essential for QGIS beginners?

Tags: qgis, references, training

What topics do you think are essential in an introduction for QGIS?

The target audience is those with zero or rudimentary knowledge in mapping and geospatial software.

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at the "gentle GIS introduction" found on the QGIS website?  Might be a good starting place to look for topics.

The address is:

http://qgis.org/en/documentation/manuals.html

It's found towards the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 9):

This [beginner's course](http://www.gbd-consult.de/en/training-courses/qgis-introduction.html) offered by GBD Consult might be a good reference. Their course covers the following topics:

> - Installation Overview and Applications of Quantum GIS
> - Introduction to the Graphical User Interface
> - Data management and fundamentals on projections
> - Integrating and analyzing vector and raster data
> - Attribute management and digitizing
> - Working with the core plug-ins
> - Integrating and working with external plugins
> - Exchange of data and layout printable maps

Answer (score 5):

There is a presentation for beginners about Qgis features that I made for an Webnar, the link is here: http://mundogeo.com/webinar/osgeo/osgeo-pablo.pdf .
It's in Portuguese but there is little text.

Editable version: http://ubuntuone.com/4Z1SToBnm4XvvKNIh56YPe

The topics that I suggest:

- Qgis is a machine, data enters and information (maps) exit.
- Qgis is open source, what is open source and the implications.
- Accept a lot of data formats through Gdal/ogr, what is raster and vectors.
- Present some qgis processing tools.
  --- That end the basics, now starts the magic:
- Qgis uses grass and postgis which creates an enormous processing power.
- what is grass.
- what is postgis.
- Qgis has an API which expose the engine under the hood and can automate repetitive tasks.  (waht is an api).
  ---  Final thoughts:
- Qgis is composed by many libraries and they are very well maintained.
- Qgis has a lot of help and support.

Answer (score 4):

Micha Silver has published a complete tutorial for qgis beginners (11 excercises), see overview here: http://www.surfaces.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Exercises.pdf
and the complete course materials here: http://www.surfaces.co.il/?p=872

Answer (score 0):

I would especially like to learn QGIS/Python tools and methods that ArcGIS users accomplish with Spatial Analyst tools, such as:

- Extract by Mask
- Raster Calculator
- Reclassify
- Zonal Statistics
- Focal Statistics
- Kernel Density
- Iso Cluster, MLC, PCA
- Hydrology Tools